# Contour integration and reversing orientation of parametrisation

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, parametrization, orientation

I have been reading through *"Complex Analysis for Mathematics & Engineering"* by *J. Matthews* and *R.Howell*, and I'm a bit confused about the way in which they have parametrised the opposite orientation of a contour $\mathcal{C}$.

Using their notation, consider a contour $\mathcal{C}$ with parametrisation $$\mathcal{C}:\;z_{1}(t)=x(t)+iy(t)\,,\;\;\; a\leq t\leq b$$ Then the opposite curve $-\mathcal{C}$ traces out the same set of points but in the reverse order, and it has the parametrisation $$-\mathcal{C}:\;z_{2}(t)=x(-t)+iy(-t)\,,\;\;\; -a\leq t\leq -b$$ They then go on to say that since $z_{2}(t)=z_{1}(-t)$, it is easy to see that $-\mathcal{C}$ is merely $\mathcal{C}$ traversed in the opposite sense.

However, I don't quite see why the contour $-\mathcal{C}$ is parametrised this way? Naively, I would've though it would be something like $$-\mathcal{C}:\;z_{2}(t)=x(t)+iy(t)\,,\;\;\; b\leq t\leq a$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a typo and the reverse parameterization should read: 
$$
-\mathcal{C}:\;z_{2}(t)=x(-t)+iy(-t)\,,\;\;\; -b\leq t\leq -a
$$

For $-b\leq t\leq -a$ we have $a\leq -t\leq b$ and $z_2(t) = x(-t) + iy(-t) = z_1(-t)$

And $z_2(-b) = z_1(b)\,, \; z_2(-a) = z_1(a)$ so $z_2$ traverses the same contour in the opposite direction from $z_1$

With regards to the naive intuition you mentioned, you can't have $b\leq t\leq a$ because you know that $a \lt b$ assuming they are different. Intuitively you want the parameterization to give the same values as $z_1(t)$ but when $t$ goes from $b$ to $a$, which is exactly what the book is doing.

Comment: Ah, so is the reason for the minus sign exactly because we are traversing the contour in the opposite direction - we want the parameter $t$ to range from $b$ to $a$, but since $b>a$, we must consider $-b$ and $-a$ since then $-b<-a$ and $t$ then ranges from $-b$ to$-a$?!

Comment: Yes, the minus sign is a way to indicate traversing the contour in the opposite direction, although it's not a formal definition. A parameterization $\theta$ takes as input a segment $[x, y]$ (where $x \lt y$) and maps it to a path that starts at $\theta(x)$ and ends at $\theta(y)$. The author finds a new parameterization $\theta(s) = -s : [-b, -a] \to [a, b]$ traversing from $b$ to $a$ because it starts from $\theta(-b)=b$ and ends at $\theta(-a)=a$. Then $z_2(t) = z_1(\theta(t)) = z_1(-t)$ where $-b \leq t \leq a$

Comment: You don't have to consider $-b$ and $-a$. You could also take $a \leq t \leq b$ and look at $z_2(t) = z_1(b-t+a)$

Comment: Ah ok. For some reason the parametrisation $z_{2}(t)=z_{1}(b-t+a)$ makes more intuitive sense to me. Would the following then be correct: $$\int_{-\mathcal{C}}f(z)dz=\int_{a}^{b}f(z(a+b-t))z'(a+b-t)dt=-\int_{b}^{a}f(z(\tau))(-z'(\tau))d\tau\\ =\int_{b}^{a}f(z(\tau))z'(\tau)d\tau=-\int_{a}^{b}f(z(\tau))z'(\tau)d\tau =-\int_{\mathcal{C}}f(z)dz$$ where in the second equality I have made the substitution of variables $\tau =a+b-t$, and have used that $z'(a+b-t)=\frac{d}{dt}(a+b-t)z'(\tau)=-z'(\tau)$.