# If $\displaystyle \int_\gamma f(z) \, dz = i$ and $\displaystyle\int_\gamma g(z)\,dz = 3-i,$ find $\displaystyle\int_{-\gamma} (2f(z) + ig(z))\,dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Can't figure our this reverse path integral at all, can anyone help?

Comment: Reversing the path changes the sign of the integral. You can prove this property by making the change of variable $t=1-s$ in the parametrized definition of that integral.

Answer (score 2):

We know that the integral along a directed smooth curve $\gamma$ is given by
$$ \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)\,dt, $$
where we have a parametrization of the curve $\gamma$ consistent with its direction.

Suposing that what is meant by "$-\gamma$" is inverting the path direction, then
$$ \int_{-\gamma} f(z)\,dz = \int_{-b}^{-a} f(\gamma(-t)) (-\gamma'(-t))\,dt = - \int_{a}^{b} f(\gamma(u))\gamma'(u)\,du = -\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz, $$
where we have performed the change of variables $u=-t$.

More details can be found in [Contour integration and reversing orientation of parametrisation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955068/contour-integration-and-reversing-orientation-of-parametrisation).

Using the above result along with the integral being a linear operator, we have that
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\gamma} (2 f(z) + i g(z))\,dz &= -\int_{\gamma} (2 f(z) + i g(z))\,dz\\
  &= -2\int_{\gamma} f(z) \,dz - i\int_{\gamma} g(z)\,dz \\
  &= -2 i - i (3-i) \\
  &= \boxed{-1 - 5i}.
\end{align*}